# android schedule task

Tags: android, service, scheduled-tasks, locationmanager

I got a task.

```
6:00 register locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, locationListener);<br>
19:00 unregister locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

First, I want to use service, with `AlarmManager`. But I can not send `locationManager` and `locationListener` from activity to service.

Finally, I use `AsyncTask` to create a loop in `doInbackground` to run all the time. If time is 6:00 or 19:00, register or unregister locationManager.

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    while(flag) {
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(calendar.getTime().getTime() - now < 1000) {
            publishProgress(new Message(Message.REMOVE_LOCATION_MANAGER));
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(calendar.getTime().getTime() - now < 1000) {
            publishProgress(new Message(Message.REGISTER_LOCATION_MANAGER));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    Message msg = (Message)values[0];
    if(msg.type == Message.REMOVE_LOCATION_MANAGER) {
        lm.removeUpdates(ll);
        Toast.makeText(context, "remove locationManager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(msg.type == Message.REGISTER_LOCATION_MANAGER) {
        lm.removeUpdates(ll);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, ll);
        Toast.makeText(context, "register locationManager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Anyone have a better schedule method, thx in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There's no point answering your question directly, and you definitely have to rethink your application, because no Android device will survive on a single battery charge while running GPS from 6AM to 19PM.

Basically you have to request GPS location updates only when you really need them. Here's a nice article by Android Guru Reto Meyer about getting location updates: http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html